# How to subsample different numbers by ID and bootstrap in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, statistics-bootstrap, subsampling

First, I'm trying to subsample a large dataset with many individuals, but each individual requires a different subsample size. I'm comparing across two time periods, so I want to subsample each individual by the minimum data points each has across the two periods. Second, I have multiple metrics (mostly various means) to calculate per individual, per time period (I've provided one example below). Third, I want to bootstrap 1,000 reps for those metrics. I also want to do this for the population (by averaging across individuals). I have an example of what I've tried below, but that may be way off. I'm open to functions or for loops - I can't conceptualize which is better for this question. (I apologize ahead of time if my code is not efficient - I'm self taught from googling.)

```
# Example dataset
Data <- data.frame(
ID = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 50, replace = TRUE),
Act = sample(c("eat", "sleep", "play"), 50, replace = TRUE),
Period = sample(c("pre", "post"), 50, replace = TRUE)
)

# Separate my data by period
DataPre <- as.data.frame(Data[ which(Data $Period == "pre"), ])
DataPost <- as.data.frame(Data[ which(Data $Period == "post"), ])

# Get the minimum # observations for each ID across both periods
Num <- Data %>% 
group_by(ID, Period) %>% 
summarise(number=n()) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarise(min=min(number)) 

# Function to get the mean proportion per ID
meanAct <- function(x){
x %>%
group_by(ID, Act) %>%
summarise (n = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
}
```

Below is how I would subsample if just ONE ID (not many different with different subsampling requirements). I don't know how to specify to subsample different amounts by ID and then replicate each.

```
# See "8888" Here I want to subsample the Num$Min for each ID
DataResults <- function(x, rep){
reps <- replicate(rep, meanAct(x[sample(1:nrow(x), 8888, replace=FALSE),]))
meanfreq <- apply(simplify2array(reps[3, 1:2]), 1, mean)
sd <- apply(simplify2array(reps[3, 1:2]), 1, sd)
lower <- meanfreq - 1.96*(sd/sqrt(8888))
upper <- meanfreq + 1.96*(sd/sqrt(8888))
meanAct <- as.vector(reps[[1]])
output <- data.frame(meanAct, meanfreq, sd, lower, upper)
print(output)
}

# Print results
DataResults(DataPre, 1000)
DataResults(DataPost, 1000)

# Somehow I get the mean for the population by averaging across all IDs
DataMeanGroup <- DataMean %>%
group_by(Period) %>%
summarise (mean = mean(prop))
```

The results I'm looking for are the means for each activity for each individual based on subsampling (by minimum datapoints PER INDIVIDUAL) and bootstrapping 1000 reps. Also, if possible, the overall mean for the population by averaging across individuals (again from subsampling and bootstrapping).

**EDIT: Additional information:**
The ultimate result should allow me to compare the proportion of time that each ID does each activity across the two time periods (e.g. compare % time that A spends eating in the pre vs post, etc). But, subsampled for the period with too much data so that we're comparing an equal number of observations. The way the code would run in my head would be (1) subsample the observations so that we’re comparing an equal number of observations for each ID across the two periods, (2) calculate the proportion of each activity for each ID in each time period, (3) repeat that subsample calculation 1,000 times so that the proportion we end up with is representative of the total observations.

Answer (score 2):

Consider generalizing your subsampling function to receive subsets of data frame passed in `by` which can slice data frame by each unique pairing of *ID* and *Period*. But first calculate `MinNum` by each *ID* and *Period* using `ave` (inline aggregation). All code below uses base R (i.e., no other package):

**Data and Functions**

```
# Example dataset (WITH MORE ROWS)
set.seed(11919)
Data <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 500, replace = TRUE),
  Act = sample(c("eat", "sleep", "play"), 500, replace = TRUE),
  Period = sample(c("pre", "post"), 500, replace = TRUE)
)

# MIN NUM PER ID AND PERIOD GROUPING (NESTED ave FOR COUNT AND MIN AGGREGATIONS)
Data$Min_Num <- with(Data, ave(ave(1:nrow(Data), ID, Period, FUN=length), ID, FUN=min))

# Function to get the mean proportion per ID
meanAct <- function(x){
  within(x, { 
        n <- ave(1:nrow(x), ID, Act, FUN=length)
        freq <- n / sum(n)
  })
}

DataResults <- function(df, rep){
  reps <- replicate(rep, meanAct(df[sample(1:nrow(df), df$Min_Num[1], replace=FALSE),]))
  mean_freq <- apply(simplify2array(reps["freq", ]), 1, mean)    # ADJUSTED [] INDEXING
  sd <- apply(simplify2array(reps["freq", ]), 1, sd)             # ADJUSTED [] INDEXING
  lower <- mean_freq - 1.96*(sd/sqrt(df$Min_Num[1]))
  upper <- mean_freq + 1.96*(sd/sqrt(df$Min_Num[1]))
  mean_act <- as.vector(reps[[2]])                               # ADJUSTED [[#]] NUMBER 
  id <- df$ID[1]                                                 # ADD GROUP INDICATOR
  period <- df$Period[1]                                         # ADD GROUP INDICATOR

  output <- data.frame(id, period, mean_act, mean_freq, sd, lower, upper)
  return(output)
}
```

**Processing**

```
# BY CALL
df_list <- by(Data, Data[c("ID", "Period")], function(sub) DataResults(sub, 1000))

# BIND ALL DFs INTO ONE DF
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
head(final_df, 10)
#    id period mean_act  mean_freq          sd      lower      upper
# 1   A   post    sleep 0.02157354 0.005704140 0.01992512 0.02322196
# 2   A   post      eat 0.02151701 0.005720058 0.01986399 0.02317003
# 3   A   post    sleep 0.02171393 0.005808156 0.02003546 0.02339241
# 4   A   post      eat 0.02164184 0.005716603 0.01998982 0.02329386
# 5   A   post     play 0.02174095 0.005678416 0.02009996 0.02338193
# 6   A   post      eat 0.02181380 0.005716590 0.02016178 0.02346581
# 7   A   post    sleep 0.02172458 0.005691051 0.02007995 0.02336922
# 8   A   post    sleep 0.02174288 0.005666839 0.02010524 0.02338052
# 9   A   post     play 0.02166234 0.005673047 0.02002291 0.02330177
# 10  A   post     play 0.02185057 0.005813680 0.02017050 0.02353065
```

**Summarization**

```
# SUMMARIZE FINAL DF (MEAN PROP BY ID AND ACT)
agg_df <- aggregate(mean_freq ~ id + mean_act, final_df, mean)
agg_df
#    id mean_act  mean_freq
# 1   A      eat 0.02172782
# 2   B      eat 0.01469706
# 3   C      eat 0.01814771
# 4   D      eat 0.01696995
# 5   A     play 0.02178283
# 6   B     play 0.01471497
# 7   C     play 0.01819898
# 8   D     play 0.01688828
# 9   A    sleep 0.02169912
# 10  B    sleep 0.01470978
# 11  C    sleep 0.01818944
# 12  D    sleep 0.01697438

# SUMMARIZE FINAL DF (MEAN PROP BY ID AND PERIOD)
agg_df <- aggregate(mean_freq ~ id + period, final_df, mean)
agg_df
#   id period  mean_freq
# 1  A   post 0.02173913
# 2  B   post 0.01470588
# 3  C   post 0.01818182
# 4  D   post 0.01694915
# 5  A    pre 0.02173913
# 6  B    pre 0.01470588
# 7  C    pre 0.01818182
# 8  D    pre 0.01694915

# SUMMARIZE FINAL DF (MEAN PROP BY ID)
agg_df <- aggregate(mean_freq ~ id, final_df, mean)
agg_df
#   id  mean_freq
# 1  A 0.02173913
# 2  B 0.01470588
# 3  C 0.01818182
# 4  D 0.01694915
```

Comment: thank you so much for your thoughtful and thorough response. I'm still working my way through it and trying to make sure I understand everything. But I wanted to acknowledge your response and tell you how appreciative I am! I've added an "EDITED" section above to clarify the question/result - to make sure the question that I'm trying to answer is in fact the question I asked (and the code I provided). And to confirm that I'm understanding the output of the code above. I do have do questions below:

Comment: For the meanAct function – should Period also be included? Or is it okay that Period is left out here because later Period is in the BY CALL section? Freq seems slow to me – shouldn’t it be the proportion of each activity per ID per Period? Here it looks like is the proportion out of the entire dataset. Is that right?

Comment: The other piece I’m trying to make sure I understand is in the DataResults function. Here it looks like we’re subsampling the mean proportion per ID from meanAct. Is that right? Or is it actively calculating a mean proportion per ID per activity per period for every subsample (1000 times)? The second is what I thought it would do – but maybe those give you the same result?

Comment: I cannot answer all your questions as it sounds more like you need formulating your needs beyond programming. Here `by` splits your data frame into smaller data frames filtered to every combination of *ID* and *Period* (if needed add *Activity*) and passes subsets into `DataResults`. So all operations within the function including `meanAct` works on filtered subsets (never the whole data frame).